# PUSH data from database to Java Servlet / PHP

Tags: oracle, push

Is there a way to push a data from say oracle database to my PHP or Java servlet which can eventually send it to my webbrowser (client)???

Answer (score 0):

of course there are. other way it would be useless technology.
for php-oracle pair look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php),
for php-mysql [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

there are tons of examples

Comment: its not about connecting to PHP its about scalability ... how can i have say 200 concurrent users receive notifications real time...!!! :-/